# How to automate a form and then retrieve the results using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I have a dataset where each row consists of a zip and address. Here's what I want the script to do:

1) Import zip code and address into form
2) Click the button (the button already gives results in div)
3) Retrieve results from that div (either by creating a list or a new column)
4) Repeat the process until there are no more zip codes and addresses

I want to do this in Python. Is this possible, and if so what packages would be able to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want selenium.

Comment: Agreed.  Here's a link to a tutorial: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the link.

Comment: You can alternatively try to mimic the request made by the form when you hit the button.